# Extract string beetween two other given strings

Tags: regex, sed, eshell

I want to keep a character string that between two others character strings. ("aa" and "cc").

The problem is if I have several "cc". I want to take into account the first "cc" and not the last "cc".

My file `monfic.txt` contains this only line:

```
aazzaczzccyyayyaattcttcc
```

And the `sed` expression I am trying:

```
sed 's/.*aa\(.*\)cc.*/\1/' monfic.txt
```

Returns:

```
zzaczzccyyayyaattctt
```

Whereas I want this to be the output:

```
zzaczz
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You should put some more effort into creating your sample input and expected output and include all the potential rainy day cases like a `cc` before the first `aa...cc` otherwise you'll probably end up with a "solution" that only works for the one case you showed us.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grep` with Perl extensions to list all the matches and then just select the match you want in a pipeline:

`grep -Po 'aa.*?cc' <<< "aazzaczzccyyayyaattcttcc" | sed -n 's/^aa//;s/cc$//;1p'`

If you need a match other than the first just change `1p` to whatever line or line range you want.
E.g. `2p` or `2p;5p;` or `1,3p;5;` etc.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/^[^a]*(a[^a]+)*aa([^c]*(c[^c]+)*)cc.*/\2/' file
```

This matches on the first `aa` followed by the first `cc` and extracts the string inbetween.